# Reparing a drives filesystem

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, encryption, lvm, fsck

Is it possible to repair the filesystem of the following drive using `fsck`?

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 59.6 GiB, 64023257088 bytes, 125045424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb173bdf0

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       1001470 125044735 124043266 59.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1001472 125044735 124043264 59.2G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-bf04fb83-73a0-4679-a468-9571c05a73b0: 59.2 GiB, 63508054016 bytes, 124039168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I get the following message when I try to mount it:

[image: Unable to mount message]

> **Unable to mount 64 GB Encrypted**
>   Operation was cancelled

Which is why I want to try to somehow repair the filesystem.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text. Instead, paste the text into your question, select it, and press the editor's `{}` button.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? Which file system do you want to repair? What *exactly* did you try, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any other warning or error messages? (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: The hold is completely not required as the question is crystal clear and was understood perfectly by @heynnema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the file systems on your Linux partitions...

- boot to the GRUB menu (where you select which OS to start)
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1`
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb5` # this command may fail
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/luks-bf04fb83-73a0-4679-a468-9571c05a73b0`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thank you.  Got the drive into a state where I was able to copy the files off.